# Update ios11.1 with Xcode 9 and iPhone 7

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode9, xcode9beta6

I was testing my application on my iPhone 7 with Xcode9beta6. All was ok when I got an iOS 11.1 update on my iPhone. Now, when I run my project, I have this message :

[image: error message]

I tried with the last Xcode9 version too but still this message.
Any idea ?

Comment: I don't have this issue in iPhone6 + Xcode 9.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help (**"why isn't this code working?"**) must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a **clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [mcve] In addition, [Do not post images of code or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303812/995714)

Comment: Sorry, that's my first question there. It isn't a code problem but a problem with Xcode and iOS11.1. I thought the screenshot of the error would be more explicit.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this yesterday. The issue was I had upgraded to iOS 11.1 Beta on my device (iPhone 6S) but I was using the production version (non beta) of  Xcode 9. This version of xCode 9 does not support iOS 11.1 Beta.

I had two options - upgrade my xCode 9 to the latest beta version or go to the backup of my iPhone and restore iOS 11.0.1.

I restored to iOS 11.0.1 successfully and now XCode works fine with the iPhone.

Hope that helps

Comment: I downgraded to iOS 11.0.1 too. I can continue to test my app on my iPhone but not on the last iOS version :/

Comment: What steps are involved with downgrading to 11.0.1? Thanks

Comment: take a look [here](http://wccftech.com/heres-how-to-downgrade-ios-11-1-beta-to-ios-11-ios-11-0-1/)

Answer (score 2):

I also faced same issue.It is because of iOS 11.1 upgrade Since Xcode 9 doest support iOS 11.1 Beta issue has been raised.Only options is either restore to older version or else test with another device which is compatible with Xcode9

Answer (score 2):

11.1 iOS Beta version not supported by XCode 9 upgrade your XCode 9.1